# openness , closure ,density of class of continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the class of all continuous function closed or open or dense in the class of piecewise continuous functions over closed and bounded intervals, under supremum norm?

Comment: In what topology? You need a topology on the set of functions you describe in order to discuss openness, closedness, and density.

Comment: under suprimum norm

Comment: So you're also assuming boundedness of the functions.  Are these functions continuous except on a finite set? A set of Lebesgue measure zero?

Comment: yes may be, we can consider both cases. but I am interested in those having finite set of discontinuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's for concreteness take the interval $[-1,1]$, and let's introduce the step function
$$\theta(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x<0\\
1 & x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$
which clearly is a piecewise-continuous function. Also I define addition of functions and multiplication with a number to be pointwise, that is, $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ and $(\alpha f)(x)=\alpha\,f(x)$.

Now we can easily prove that the set of continuous functions is not open:
Be $f$ a continuous function on $[-1,1]$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ $g_\epsilon := f+\epsilon\theta$ is discontinuous at $0$, and $\|g-f\| = \epsilon$. Thus $f$ lies in the boundary of the set of continuous functions, and thus that set cannot be open.

The set is also not dense. Assume again that $f$ is continuous. Then we have:
$$d_f:=\|f-\theta\| = \sup_{x\in[-1,1]} |f(x)-\theta(x)| = \max\{\sup_{x\in[-1,0)}|f(x)|,\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-1|\}$$
If the set of continuous functions were dense, there would be $f$ such that $d_f$ would be arbitrary small; in particular, there would have to exist $f$ such that $d_f<\frac12$. But if $d_f<\frac12$ then $\sup_{x\in[-1,0)}|f(x)|<\frac12$. However since $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)<\frac12$. But that means $|f(0)-\theta(0)| = |1-f(0)| > \frac12$ and therefore $d_f>\frac12$, in contradiction to $d<\frac12$.

I suspect the set is closed, but I'm not sure how to prove it.